# Info doesn't get inserted to table

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, insert

My problem is that
it does not insert info to the table.
Please read the code and tell me what is the problem.
I also don't get any errors from the database
because this thing won't stop bugging me about telling more details.

**This is the HTML:**

```
<div id="middle" class="col">
    <br><br>
    <p class="text-center"><strong> فرم ثبت نام</strong></p>
    <br><p class="text-center"> اجباری<span><strong style="color:red">&nbsp *</strong></p><br>

  <form method="post" style="height:70vh; width:47vw; text-align:center;" action="">
    <table width="75%">

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username?>"></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right" height="1.5em">:شناسه<font color="red">&nbsp;*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password?>">
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right" height="1.5em">:رمزعبور<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $password_checkErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="password" name="password_check" value="<?php echo $password_check ?>">
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right" height="1.5em">:تکرار رمز عبور<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $fnameErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname?>"></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right">: نام<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $lastnameErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname?>"></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right">: نام خانوادگی<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email?>"></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right">:پست الکترونیک<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $phone_numberErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="<?php echo $phonenumber?>" ></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right">:تلفن ثابت<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $cellphone_numberErr?></span></td>
            <td align="right"><input type="text" name="cellphonenumber" value="<?php echo $cellphonenumber?>" ></td>
            <td style="font-size:medium" align="right">:موبایل<font color="red">&nbsp*</font>&emsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan=3 align=right>
            <table border=0>
                <tr><br>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $state?>" >
                </td>
                <td colspan=2 align=right>
                    &emsp;&emsp;:استان<font style="font-size:medium" color="red">&nbsp*&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;</font>
                </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td><span class="error"><?php echo $addressErr?></span></td>
                <td> <textarea name="address" row+4><?php echo $address?></textarea></td>
                <td style="font-size:medium" colspan=2 align="right">&ensp;:نشانی<font color="red">&nbsp*&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;</font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="error"><?php echo $zipcodeErr?></span></td>
                <td align="right"><input type="text" name="zipcode" value="<?php echo $zipcode?>"></td>
                <td id="address" style="font-size:medium" colspan=2 align="right">&ensp;:کد پستی<font color="red">&nbsp*&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&ensp;</font></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <br><span class="text-center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="ثبت" style="height:3vh"></span>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
  </form>
```

**this is the php,mysql:**

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $zipcode = $username = $password = $password_check = $lname = $state
     = $fname = $email = $cellphonenumber = $address = $phonenumber ="";


    $zipcodeErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $password_checkErr = $lastnameErr = $stateErr
     = $fnameErr = $emailErr = $cellphone_numberErr = $addressErr = $phone_numberErr = "";


    $anyerror=0;
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mysql');

// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error)
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyUsers6 (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            phonenumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            cellphonenumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            zipcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            reg_date TIMESTAMP,
            primary key (id)
    )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE)
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;



    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


    if (empty($_POST["username"])){
        $usernameErr ="لطفا شناسه خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);

    if (empty($_POST["state"])){
        $stateErr ="لطفا شناسه خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);


    if (empty($_POST["password"])){
        $passwordErr = "لطفا رمزعبور خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);


    if (empty($_POST["password_check"])){
        $password_checkErr = "لطفا رمزعبور را دوباره وارد کنید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    if(strcmp($password,$password_check) ==0 && isset($_POST["password_check"])){
        $password_checkErr = " رمز عبور ها یکسان نیستند";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $password_check = test_input($_POST["password_check"]);


    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "لطفا نام خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);


    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lastnameErr = "لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
        else 
        $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "فرمت ایمیل غیرمجاز است";
        $anyerror=1;
    }
    else 
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);


    if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"])) {
        $phone_numberErr = "لطفا شماره تلفن خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $phonenumber = test_input($_POST["phonenumber"]);


    if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
        $addressErr = "لطفا نشانی خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);


    if (empty($_POST["cellphonenumber"])) {
        $cellphone_numberErr = "لطفا شماره موبایل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $cellphonenumber = test_input($_POST["cellphonenumber"]);


    if (empty($_POST["zipcode"])) {
        $zipcodeErr = "لطفا شماره موبایل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $zipcode = test_input($_POST["zipcode"]);


    if ( $anyerror = 0 )
            $sql = "INSERT INTO MyUsers6 VALUES ('$username' ,'$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$phonenumber', '$cellphonenumber', '$email', '$state', '$address', '$zipcode')";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) 
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        else
            echo "ssssssss";

    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Its actually 'How to get along'.. (rhymes with wrong)..

Comment: Do you return any error from the db?

Comment: no i don't and that is the main problem

Comment: @Amirali I saw that your form's action is empty so it means that you are checking and sending data in the same page ,but I didn't see any check if the form is submitted!!

Comment: if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") // if the form has been submited, validate and if no error insert the data into the table ... @Mr.NaViD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//change your database name put this code and check it
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $zipcode = $username = $password = $password_check = $lname = $state
     = $fname = $email = $cellphonenumber = $address = $phonenumber ="";


    $zipcodeErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $password_checkErr = $lastnameErr = $stateErr
     = $fnameErr = $emailErr = $cellphone_numberErr = $addressErr = $phone_numberErr = "";


    $anyerror=0;
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error)
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyUsers6 (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
            username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            phonenumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            cellphonenumber VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            zipcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            reg_date TIMESTAMP,
            primary key (id)
    )";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE)
        echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;



    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {


    if (empty($_POST["username"])){
        $usernameErr ="لطفا شناسه خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);

    if (empty($_POST["state"])){
        $stateErr ="لطفا شناسه خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);


    if (empty($_POST["password"])){
        $passwordErr = "لطفا رمزعبور خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);


    if (empty($_POST["password_check"])){
        $password_checkErr = "لطفا رمزعبور را دوباره وارد کنید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    if(strcmp($password,$password_check) ==0 && isset($_POST["password_check"])){
        $password_checkErr = " رمز عبور ها یکسان نیستند";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else
        $password_check = test_input($_POST["password_check"]);


    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $fnameErr = "لطفا نام خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);


    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $lastnameErr = "لطفا نام خانوادگی خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
        else 
        $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "فرمت ایمیل غیرمجاز است";
        $anyerror=1;
    }
    else 
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);


    if (empty($_POST["phonenumber"])) {
        $phone_numberErr = "لطفا شماره تلفن خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $phonenumber = test_input($_POST["phonenumber"]);


    if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
        $addressErr = "لطفا نشانی خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);


    if (empty($_POST["cellphonenumber"])) {
        $cellphone_numberErr = "لطفا شماره موبایل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $cellphonenumber = test_input($_POST["cellphonenumber"]);


    if (empty($_POST["zipcode"])) {
        $zipcodeErr = "لطفا شماره موبایل خود را وارد نمایید";
        $anyerror=1;}
    else 
        $zipcode = test_input($_POST["zipcode"]);

    if ( $anyerror == 0 ) {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO MyUsers6 (username,password,fname,lname,phonenumber,cellphonenumber,email,state,address,zipcode)
VALUES ('$username' ,'$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$phonenumber', '$cellphonenumber', '$email', '$state', '$address', '$zipcode')";
           }

        if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) 
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        else
            echo "ssssssss";

    }

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: you also have problem in if condition

Comment: what is the problem with if condition?

Comment: you were assigning value to your $anyerror variable like this
$anyerror = 0 before insert query
here we need to compare the value like $anyerror  == 0

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax problem in your SQL query.
you have to specify the column you want to insert data to,but you haven't done it.

```
INSERT INTO(column1,column2) VALUES('value1','value2')
```

So you have to update you code:

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO MyUsers6**(your columns)** VALUES ('', '$username' ,'$password', '$fname', '$lname', '$phonenumber', '$cellphonenumber', '$email', '$state', '$address', '$address', '')";
```

Comment: actually that is not a syntax problem, if u don't specify it will add based on the order u created table...the first one will go to username, second goes to password,third goes to fname ....

Comment: @Amirali I think when you want to pass a auto_increment field you have to specify the columns you want to insert to!!

Comment: first off you shouldn't be passing the autoinc column. You were, and the data blew up by passing ''. But you never had error reporting turned on to know it.

Comment: @Mr.NaViD yep, that was one problem , the other was mysql database -_- changed it to test and it worked like a charm :D

Comment: @Amirali if it helped so please choose it as the correct answer:)thanks

Comment: @Mr.NaViD u can only choose one as the correct answer, the other guy said both problems, so his should be the correct answer... ;)

Comment: @Amirali yep,you are right.I didn't mention the other problem:-). wish you success;)

Comment: @Mr.NaViD any idea how can i turn this to code to a mvc one?